# C# - XML Validation with XSD - Presenting results in Listbox and Treeview

Tags: c#, xml, validation, listbox, treeview

**Hello all!**

I have the following use case:

My Winform-App is validating a prarticular XML against the XSD and displays the errors (if any) in a listbox (this works fine). In addition to that I load the validated XML into a treeview.

Now, what I would like to achieve is to give the user the ability to doubleklick the error in the listbox to have then the treeview selecting the relevant element which caused the error.

I'm a little stuck with this actually. I now the row number of the error, but I can't select the relevant node in the treeview by using the row number.

[image: Printcreen of Validation App]
[image: Printscreen of XML]

Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve this?

Any hint is very much appreciated :)

kind regards

UPDATE:

Code filling the treeview:

```
doc.Load(XMLDocPath);
XmlNodeTree root = new XmlNodeTree(0, doc.LastChild);
treeDGUXml.Nodes.Add(root);
FillTreeView(root.Nodes, doc.LastChild.ChildNodes);
```

And the method:

```
private void FillTreeView(TreeNodeCollection c, XmlNodeList l)
{
  if (l == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  foreach (XmlNode e in l)
  {
    XmlNodeTree n = new XmlNodeTree(nRow, e);
    c.Add(n);
    FillTreeView(n.Nodes, e.ChildNodes);
  }
```

And the Class:

```
public class XmlNodeTree : TreeNode
{
  private XmlNode mNode;
  public XmlNode Node
  {
    get { return mNode; }
  }

  public XmlNodeTree(int rownumber, XmlNode node)
  {
    mNode = node;
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
      Text = node.InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
      Text = rownumber.ToString() + " - " + node.Name;
      nRow++;
    }

    if (node.Attributes != null)
    {
      foreach (XmlAttribute a in node.Attributes)
      {
        Text += " " + a.OuterXml;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you used xml linq you can use List<XElement> children = doc.Descendants().ToList();  Then the children will be indexed.

Comment: Thx for the quick feedback. Actually I have some troubles understanding your hint -.-

I have added the relevant code above for better understading. The problem is that I cannot use the rownumbers coming from the validation errors, since the treview does not show the closing xml tags like </....>

Comment: How about this : doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.GetType() != XmlNodeType.EndElement.GetType()) && (x.GetType() != XmlNodeType.Text.GetType())).ToList();

Comment: hmm...the problem is that doc.Descendants().... is giving me an error

System.Xml.XmlDocument does not contain a definition for .....

Comment: the error mentioned above is because I use XmlDocument (from System.Xml) instead of XDocument (from System.Xml.Linq). The Problem is I cannot use XDocument because then other parte would not work anymore...

Comment: You could load xml into xdocument just to get line numbers.

Comment: does not work either..then 

doc.Descendants().Where(...

is giving me the error...and also other properties etc are not available anymore -.-

Comment: You would need to load xml with XDocument docLinq = XDocument.Load(XMLDocPath);

Comment: Thank you very much jdweng.

I cannot use XDocument because then I would have troubles with other properties I need using XmlDocument.

I decided to have another approach without treeview.

I load the XML into a richtext box with appropriate coloring. This way I cen select the relevant text. The user cannot collapse the xml structure, but this now is better than nothing ;)

Thank you anyway for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the hints. I decided to have another approach without treeview. I load the XML into a richtext box with appropriate coloring. This way I can select the relevant text. The user cannot collapse the xml structure, but this now is better than nothing ;) Thank you anyway for your suggestions! –